# How do I identify which Sweave code chunk gives an error?

Tags: r, emacs, sweave, ess, noweb

When running Sweave from emacs-ess, errors are provided with a code chunk number. Is there an easy way to navigate among the code chunks by number? Otherwise, they are difficult to identify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use emacs-ess (I use Eclipse/ StatEt) but this shows which code chunks are being processed by label (each code chunk starts with `<<label="Some Text"...`  Does your code chunks include labels ?

Comment: So far, counting chunks worked for me. But I may consider using labels from now on.

Comment: I agree. Labels are the way to go. I label most code blocks. In addition to aiding debugging, you can reuse code blocks, and importantly, it helps with the general readability of your Sweave document.

Answer (score 2):

In noweb mode in emacs <kbd>M-n i</kbd> inserts the chunk and asks for the label. You can navigate between them with <kbd>M-n g</kbd> which is very handy with completion packages like `ido` or `icicles`. With ido you must use this [hack](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings#toc13) to activate it for all completion-read based functions such as `noweb-goto-chunk` from above.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that might help is setting `options(error=recover)` in your R environment before sweaving.  That will give you a chance to investigate the state of things just before an error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks. I finally implemented this and it is really helpful.